# A presentable way to plot frequency of 43 distinct classes

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, machine-learning

I created the following histogram from the frequeny of each class in a training set

[image]

The label of each class is too long and is similar to

```
Speed limit (20km/h)
```

Can I place each label on the bar itself?

Comment: You may consider separating this into two questions as one seems to be how can I label a histogram (change the plot size, etc) while the second is how do I add a legend. You might also consider expanding the explanation of the second as I'm guessing on what your even asking there. As it seems a measure of the correlation of three groups based on a probability density to a precision level - and I could be completely off - which would need more of a legend then an axis label.

Comment: @JGreenwell also created a second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133542/plotting-training-data-with-43-distinct-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=5
xlabel = ["Speed limit ("+str(i)+"km/h)" for i in range(0,N)]
xs = np.arange(0,7,1.5)
ys = [8,6,10,7,9]
width = 0.3*np.ones(N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(xs, ys, width, color='k',alpha=0.3)
plt.xticks(xs, xlabel,rotation=270)

for i,bar in enumerate(bars):
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2., 0.1*height,
                '%s' % xlabel[i],rotation=90,ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

To change it to horizontal bar plot:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
xlabel = ["Speed limit ("+str(i)+"km/h)" for i in range(0,5)]
xs = np.arange(0,5)/2
ys = [8,6,10,7,9]
width = 0.3*np.ones(N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.barh(xs, ys, width, color='k',alpha=0.3)
plt.xticks([])

for i,bar in enumerate(bars):
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax.text(bar.get_x()+3, bar.get_y()+bar.get_height()/3,
                '%s' % xlabel[i],rotation=0,ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is *width* in bars = ax.bar(xs, ys, width, color='k',alpha=0.3)?  nvm used 0.5 and it looks good!

Comment: Excellent answer.  I'm working on making it a *barh* at the moment.  If you can to add that as well I would be greatful!